# #include library files in c

Tags: c, header-files

I have a library in c one of the files has name something like this :

```
template.h
```

but inside the code call the header in this way

```
#include "template/template.h"
```

I have not file in this name  `template/template.h` in the folder.
Is that the same file or what that mean? because when run the code that call `"template/template.h"` I got on `template/template.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you have a folder named `template`? If not, remove the `template/`.

Comment: First of all please read [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename?rq=2)

Comment: Then please note that `#include "template/template.h"` will cause the compiler to search for the `template/template.h` directory-file pair. It's the actual hierarchy as laid out on the drive itself.

Comment: @Bob__ , Yes I have folder named template, yes now I understand that mean the folder name and the file name, is that correct?

Comment: Where is the directory `template` located? In the same directory as the source-file you're trying to compile? In one of the system directories that the compiler automatically searches? Perhaps you need to tell the compiler where the `template` directory is located? For example with the `-I` (upper-case i) option (for GCC and Clang).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes in the same directory as the source-file

Comment: Is the *file* `template.h` in the same directory, or the *sub-directory* `template`? Can you please [edit] your question to try and show the directory hierarchy?

Comment: Succinctly, if the header file is `/home/someone/project/template/template.h`, and your code contains `#include <template/template.h>`, then your compilation command line on most systems will need to contain the equivalent of `-I /home/someone/project` so that concatenating the directory name, a `/`, and the name in angle brackets corresponds to the pathname of the header.  Windows might use backslashes instead of slashes, and might use `/I` instead of `-I`,  and the compilation might give the relative path instead of the absolute path for the directory, and so on — hence "the equivalent of".

Answer (score 0):

The difference between headers that look like

```
#include "template.h"
```

and those that look like

```
#include <template/template.h>
```

is that the earlier requires that header file to exist in the same folder as the source file while the later needs the header file added to the environment via adding the paths to the **include** and **lib** folders of the library associated with that header.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to specify the file path correctly. If there is a file in a directory called "template" and the file name is **'template.h'**, then you will specify the name like this: **`#include <template/template.h>`**
Also, you will write header in `#include` if it is in project files or in the compiler's **'include'** Directory.
Also, check spelling; there maybe some mistake or you have not mentioned the path correctly, like if you have a project and its path is "/project/template/template.h".

Comment: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename?rq=2) `#include<template/template.h>` is most likely wrong.